# Cross-browser pure-javascript-based popover tool?

Tags: javascript, popover

I've been tasked with what seems to me to be impossible. I need to add a cross-browser javascript-based xhtml/css popover - something like Lightbox, shadownbox, etc. just a modal information popover that shows on page load - to "some pages".

"Some pages" is a collection of about 30 apache vhosts, hosting 6 or 7 different domains and subdomains. Some of them are serving static HTML, some are Wordpress, MediaWiki, etc. So, I'm looking for *some* method as close to `<script source="http://foo.example.com/popover.js></script>` as I can come, i.e. a single JS script include on "any" page, and then a popover written by the JS. Obviously something as lightweight as possible is best.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated....

Comment: It's not impossible: if you can implement the functionality with a library then you can implement it with "pure Javascript", though in effect then your included JS source file _is_ the library. Find a library that does what you want and then see how it does it so you can implement something similar as a standalone include.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the solution from:
http://point47.com/journal/2010/06/modal-box-on-page-load-with-jquery-fancy-box-and-cookie-plugin/

along with some jQuery script loading.

Answer (score 1):

Most popover plugins or code is going to depend on jQuery or another framework. The one that I like best is prettyPoppin.

http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettypopin/

If you wanted to support pages that don't already include jQuery you could create a script like

```
if( typeof jQuery === 'undefined' ) 
  document.write( unescape('%3Cscript type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"%3E%3C/script%3E' ) );
document.write( unescape('%3Cscript type="text/javascript" src="path to plugin"%3E%3C/script%3E' ) );

callPluginMethodThatShowsPopOver({content: ''});
```

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery UI package has a dialog plugin that supports a modal version of a popover.

That being said, your requirements are rather vague and fairly broad, so I'm not sure what you are looking for in an answer.

Comment: Well... i guess, does anyone know of a simple-to-deploy JS tool that will setup the popup by only including one remote JS file? I.e. add the html elements needed, do the ajax request to retrieve remote content for the popup, etc.? In a way that will work on "most" browsers, and "most" arbitrary pages (html, mediawiki, wordpress, etc.)?

Comment: So, assuming that you know how to write some fairly basic javascript, you can write a single script that will take care of loading in the needed jQuery libraries and call the functions needed to show the popup. Adding in content at that point also isn't hard, but you have to put in a bit of effort. Very seldom does the world provide a catch-all solution to fairly uncommon needs.